# Add Validation Message To View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

Lets say I have a form with no model binding or data annotations. When the form is posted how can I return the view with a validation message beneath the control - Note I'm trying to do server side validation here?

Below is a kind of example.

```
<input name="Address" type="text" value="">
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Address" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>


 public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
 {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(collection["Address"])
        {
            // Set the field validation error span message
            ModelState.AddModelError("Address", "This field is required.");

            return View();
        }   
 }
```

Note: I know how add validation using a view model and data annotations. In this scenario I'm unable to use a view model so need some way to manually validate and return the validation messages back to the view.

The above doesn't seem to work

*** Update ***

Perhaps using viewData as follows:

```
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Address" data-valmsg-replace="true">@ViewData["Address"]</span>
```

Comment: Have your tried adding `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Address, "")`    beneath the control? This should display all model state errors added in your controller for that property. Also there is `@Html.ValidationSummary()` which displays all model state errors.

Comment: Do what zgood said and also return your model to your view.  `return View(collection)`

Comment: Also, don't forget to separate your ActionResults for  your Get and Post, not sure if you are trying to combine both here.

Comment: Last bit for me, in this instance you should put the `[Required]` data attribute above your Address property in your model and let the asp.net engine handle this type of validation for you.

Comment: @David there is no model involved so unable to use data annotations

Comment: @zgood there is no model involved.

Comment: @adam78 Then why are you calling `.AddModelError` if there is no model?

Comment: Without a model, you will need to roll your own with [jquery validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) or perhaps angular.

Comment: @zgood so should i be using `viewdata["Address"]` or something? What if there are multiple errors for the same field and I only want to display the first on each post back?

Comment: @SteveGreene I can do client side validation. I'm trying to do server side validation.

Comment: @adam78 Well, you could cram all your validation errors in a Dictionary or some type of collection and put that in the `ViewBag` or whatever, then iterate through that in the View. But without a model all of the seems off. How will you display the values back on the form when it fails validation? It would be a blank form with just validation errors and the user would have to fill out all the fields again.

Comment: @adam78 I would suggest you make a "ViewModel" for this as it will make everything much easier.

Comment: I second the poinion of @DavidLee. This is the kind of tasks you either have to make it better(for you and everyone around you) or run away

Answer (score 1):

I would go with html helpers.

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("Address")
```

This will automatically generate the HTML:

```
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="address" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>`
```

Your code looks correct.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(collection["Address"]))
{
  // Set the field validation error span message
  ModelState.AddModelError("Address", "This field is required.");
 return View();
}
```